# Variadic template: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided (deduction error)

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-function

Look at this code snippet

```
template<class T> 
void print(T var)
{
    std::cout << var << " ";
}
 
template<class... Args> 
void Variadic(Args... args)
{
    print(args...);
}

int main()
{
     Variadic();
}
```

When I compile it says:

> **candidate: template void print(T)**
>
> **candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided**

And he's right. In fact, I didn't provide any argument in the Parameter Pack.

But why, then, this code compiles?

```
template<class T> 
void print(T var)
{
    std::cout << var << " ";
}
 
template<class... Args> 
void Variadic(Args... args)
{
    auto x = {0, (print(args), 0)...};
}

int main()
{
     Variadic();
}
```

The first thing I do is to push the first 0 into the **initializer_list<>**

Ok, now let’s move on: the compiler sees

```
(print(args), 0)...
```

It tries to call print()… oh wait… the **Parameter Pack** is empty and the print() function takes 1 parameter.

Why does it evaluate to `auto x = {0};`, then?

Why doesn't the compiler give me the exact same error as before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand how the `...` expansion operator works. In your example, when `args` is an empty pack, `(print(args), 0)...` expands to nothing, not `print()`.

If `args` was given as `x` it would expand to `print(x), 0`.

If `args` was given as `x, y` it would expand to `(print(x), 0), (print(y), 0)`.

etc.

Basically it expands all of the expression that contains `args` and it is applied to, not just the `args` bit itself.

From the standard [temp.variadic]:

> 4. A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the
>      instantiation of which produces **zero or more instantiations of the
>      pattern in a list**. The form of the pattern depends on the context in
>      which the expansion occurs.
>
> ...
>
> 7. The instantiation of a pack expansion that is neither a sizeof... expression nor a fold-expression produces a list E1, E2, ..., EN ,
>      where N is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters.
>      **Each Ei is generated by instantiating the pattern and replacing each
>      pack expansion parameter with its ith element**.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, since the Parameter Pack is empty, my `(print(args), 0)...` evaluates to nothing? So I end up with `auto x = {0};`
(the zero you see is the first one I pushed)

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ *standard 14.5.3/p4 Variadic templates [temp.variadic]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, **the
>   instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations** of the
>   pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends
>   on the context in which the expansion occurs.

Notice the *zero or more*. In your case there's an empty pack so instantiations of the pattern `(print(args), 0)...` are zero. Consequently, you don't get a compile time error because expression:

```
auto x = {0, (print(args), 0)...};
```

actually evaluates to:

```
auto x = {0};
```

that is, `print` is never called in the code generated by the compiler.

Comment: I don't think it evaluates to `auto x = {0,0};`
I think it becomes just `auto x = {0};` since the Parameter Pack is empty

DEMO >> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21723ed6d3b33b2e